# About existential graphs

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

I would like to read articles about Peirce's existential graphs. I already have the works of Brady and Trimble on it, and I would like to know if there exists a geometric approach to them, or a categorical one. Thanks!

Comment: The following is useful: [Peirce's Logic of Continuity: A Conceptual and Mathematical Approach](https://www.amazon.com/Peirces-Logic-Continuity-Conceptual-Mathematical/dp/0983700494)